# PyQt: viewing query results in a document or .txt file

Tags: python, sql, pyqt, report

Is it possble to view results of this query (and queries alike) in a .txt or .doc or any printable file, which user can then save wherever he likes and prints if he wants to?

```
query.setQuery(""" SELECT * FROM "%s" WHERE METAPHONE("%s", 3) = METAPHONE('%s', 3) OR LEVENSHTEIN("%s", '%s') < 4 """ % (str(self.search_from_table_lineEdit.text()), str(self.search_where_lineEdit.text()), str(self.search_has_value_lineEdit.text()), str(self.search_where_lineEdit.text()), str(self.search_has_value_lineEdit.text())))
                     global var
                     var = QtGui.QTableView()
                     var.setModel(query)
                     var.show()
```

**EDIT:**
I tried this:

```
class report_GUI(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_report_Widget):
       def __init__(self):
              QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
              self.setupUi(self)
              self.report_Create_Report_button.clicked.connect(self.report_data)

       def report_data(self):
              FILE_NAME = 'export.csv'
              exportQSqlQueryModel = QSqlQueryModel()
              exportQSqlQueryModel.setQuery(""" SELECT * FROM "%s" WHERE "%s" = '%s' """ % (str(self.report_from_table_lineEdit.text()), str(self.report_where_lineEdit.text()), str(self.report_has_value_lineEdit.text())))
              exportFile = open(FILE_NAME, 'wt')
              writer = csv.writer(exportFile)

              for row in exportQSqlQueryModel.rowCount():
                     listsTmpData = []
                     for column in exportQSqlQueryModel.columnCount():
                            listsTmpData.append(str(exportQSqlQueryModel.record(row).value(column).toString()))
                     writer.writerow(listsTmpData)
              exportFile.close()
```

And got this error:

```
line 563, in report_data
    for row in exportQSqlQueryModel.rowCount():
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

**EDIT2**:

```
def report_data(self):
              FILE_NAME = 'export.csv'
              exportQSqlQueryModel = QSqlQueryModel()
              exportQSqlQueryModel.setQuery(""" SELECT * FROM "%s" WHERE "%s" = '%s' """ % (str(self.report_from_table_lineEdit.text()), str(self.report_where_lineEdit.text()), str(self.report_has_value_lineEdit.text())))
              exportFile = open(FILE_NAME, 'wt')
              writer = csv.writer(exportFile)

              if (self.report_from_table_lineEdit.text() == "pacijent"):
                  exportQSqlQueryModel.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'OIB pacijenta')
                  exportQSqlQueryModel.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Prezime')
                  exportQSqlQueryModel.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Ime')
                  exportQSqlQueryModel.setHeaderData(3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'ID sobe')
                  exportQSqlQueryModel.setHeaderData(4, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Adresa')
                  exportQSqlQueryModel.setHeaderData(5, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Datum rodjenja')
                  exportQSqlQueryModel.setHeaderData(6, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Spol')

              listsTmpData = []
              for row in range(exportQSqlQueryModel.rowCount()):
                     listsTmpData.append(str(exportQSqlQueryModel.headerData(row, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)))
              writer.writerow(listsTmpData)

              for row in range(exportQSqlQueryModel.rowCount()):
                     listsTmpData = []
                     for column in range(exportQSqlQueryModel.columnCount()):
                            listsTmpData.append(str(exportQSqlQueryModel.record(row).value(column)))
                     writer.writerow(listsTmpData)
              exportFile.close()
```

It shows only the first 4 column titles and it looks like this: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2guxf5t.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend use csv to easy to read it. Read example [this](http://pymotw.com/2/csv/).

Little example;

```
import csv
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql

FILE_NAME = 'export.csv'
# .
# .
# .

exportQSqlQueryModel = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
exportQSqlQueryModel.setQuery('YOUR QUERY')
# .
# . # Do anything in query
# .

# Open file
exportFile = open(FILE_NAME, 'wt')
writer     = csv.writer(exportFile)

# If your don't have header data, Your can delete this section
listsTmpData = []
for column in range(exportQSqlQueryModel.columnCount()):
    listsTmpData.append(str(exportQSqlQueryModel.headerData(column, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal).toString()))
writer.writerow(listsTmpData)

# Write file
for row in range(exportQSqlQueryModel.rowCount()):
    listsTmpData = []
    for column in range(exportQSqlQueryModel.columnCount()):
        listsTmpData.append(str(exportQSqlQueryModel.record(row).value(column).toString()))
    writer.writerow(listsTmpData)
exportFile.close()
```

If your want header in export file, please set header in [`QSqlQueryMode.setHeaderData`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsqlquerymodel.html#setHeaderData) and write them before export data;

```
.
.
.
exportQSqlQueryModel.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Name')
exportQSqlQueryModel.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Age')
.
.
.
listsTmpData = []
for column in range(exportQSqlQueryModel.columnCount()):
    listsTmpData.append(str(exportQSqlQueryModel.headerData(column, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal).toString()))
writer.writerow(listsTmpData)
.
.
.
```

To view your data in `open office calc`, your config use `Comma` to spite your data correctly;

[image: csv view with open office calc]

Comment: Now I get this: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toString'`

Comment: It maybe python string at line `str(exportQSqlQueryModel.record(row).value(column).toString())`. Try this `str(exportQSqlQueryModel.record(row).value(column))`.

Comment: It works now :) Although, it looks kinda bad. Is it possible to put name of the columns at the top? For now it gives me data that I want, but it doesn't say to which column does data belong.

Comment: Yes, It can. Use `QSqlQueryModel.setHeaderData`. See my answer again.

Comment: It's still not pretty as I'd like it to be :D. I've edited my post

Comment: I've managed to get headers working, I had to replace row with column in all 3 places, so now it's: `for column in range...columnCount()...column, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)`, but it still looks awful. I guess there is no way to make it look like a real two dimensional table?

Comment: Ummm, I forget as your say (replace row with column).
It's real two dimensional table,But your have to config your table viewer spilt row and column. (spilt column by `,` and spite row by '\n')

Comment: your microsoft office excel. (But I use open office calc)

Comment: Oh I see, I thought I had to change something in my code.

Comment: So, every time I create .csv file, I have to manually configure it to look like a 2D table?

Comment: Yes, It is feature of csv. If your want to not config it anything, Your can use another format, such as xls, xlsx, etc. But your have to find library or module to plug it in python.

Answer (score 0):

if you had this code alone in a `.py` file in a linux terminal simply do this command :

```
python your_file_nam > ex_file.txt
```